# Google Analytics API BatchRequest - Filtering/Callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to submit a BatchRequest and unsure of how to apply a filter or how to handle the callback.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new Program().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        var privatekey = "private key";
        var accountEmailAddress = "email address";

        var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmailAddress) {
                Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }
            }.FromPrivateKey(privatekey));

        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "Test"
        });

        var request = new BatchRequest(service);

        request.Queue<DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest>(service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:XXXXXX", "30daysAgo", "yesterday", "ga:sessions"),
            (content, error, i, message) =>
            {
                //callback code
            });

        await request.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

### Two Questions:

1. How do I apply the following filter to the request?

   ```
   ga:pagePath==/page1.html
   ```
2. How do I handle the callback and view the data returned?

---

### Update

I believe I have solved the filter issue with the following code:

```
var req = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:XXXXXX", "30daysAgo", "yesterday", "ga:sessions");
req.Filters = "ga:pagePath==/page1.html";

request.Queue<DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest>(req,
    (content, error, i, message) =>
    {
        //callback code
    });
```

I am still unsure of how to handle the callback.  The "content" parameter is returned as the class: Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to get this working.

For future reference for anyone, here is a working .Net example of submitting a BatchRequest to the Analytics API.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new Program().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        var privatekey = "private key";
        var accountEmailAddress = "email address";

        var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmailAddress)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }
            }.FromPrivateKey(privatekey));

        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "Test"
        });
        var request = new BatchRequest(service);

        BatchRequest.OnResponse<GaData> callback = (content, error, i, message) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                if (content.Rows != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in content.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (var item1 in item)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
                }
            }
        };

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < 5)
        {
            var req = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:XXXXX", "30daysAgo", "yesterday", "ga:sessions");
            req.Filters = "ga:pagePath==/page" + counter + ".html";
            request.Queue<GaData>(req, callback);
            counter++;
        }

        await request.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not familiar with C# but I did look at the [source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/c2831190dc9d7a6b8e43f4df401f000b924e7de9/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.cs#L853) for the get method. And the `GetRequest` object has a filters property which you can set.

```
var request = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:XXXXXX",
    "30daysAgo", "yesterday", "ga:sessions");
request.dimensions("ga:pagePath");
request.filters("ga:pagePath==/page1.html");
```

I would encourage you to also look at the [Core Reporting API reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#introduction) for the full set of parameters.

I would imagine that the content object in the callback method would correspond to the [GaData response object](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/c2831190dc9d7a6b8e43f4df401f000b924e7de9/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.cs#L10622)

I hope that helps some.

Comment: That is the correct format for a regular get request, however, it does not work for a BatchRequest.